# SQL how to add a row before root in json

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have the following data:

```
create table samplejson (recordId varchar(10), docNumber varchar(10))
insert into samplejson values ('1', '555555')
insert into samplejson values ('2', '777777')
```

I'd like to have a "dbName" at the top of my json to designate which database this came from.  Like this:

```
{ "dbName": "test123",
  "documents": [
    {
      "json": {
        "RecordId": "1",
        "docNumber": "555555"
      }
    },
    {
      "json": {
        "RecordId": "2",
        "docNumber": "777777"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I can get my entire structure correct with this:

```
select recordId [json.RecordId],
docNumber [json.docNumber]
from samplejson
for json path, root('documents')
```

I'm just struggling to figure out a way to add my "dbName" element before the root.  Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You may change the statement like this:

```
SELECT
   DB_NAME() AS dbName,
   ( 
   select recordId [json.RecordId], docNumber [json.docNumber]
   from samplejson
   for json path
   ) AS [documents]
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```